# Why Windbg cannot see memory leaks created in delphi?

Tags: delphi, debugging, windbg

As the subject says, why windbg cannot see any memory allocated in delphi? For instance !heap -s gives nothing, while there is a 10MB memory leak intentionally created just for testing purposes.

How can delphi allocate memory without taking it from the heap?

Comment: Is it listed if you allocate it with HeapAlloc?

Comment: Objects in Delphi are usually not allocated with HeapAlloc directly, but these object are still created on heap, because they cannot be created anywhere else.

Comment: I know very well how Delphi's memory allocation works, having recently written a memory manager that wraps `HeapAlloc`. My point is that I wonder if WinDbg is only reporting heap memory allocated through `HeapAlloc`.

Comment: Great, should I create a new question: "how do you find memory leaks in Delphi with Windbg?"?

Comment: Btw, I'm obviously wrong when I think that there is one heap. There is obviously a whole jungle of memory regions from where somebody could allocate a chunk and use it.

Comment: Everything comes from `VirtualAlloc`. But on top of that there are many options for heap suballocators. `HeapAlloc` is one, and a good one. I use it in my multithreaded program because it scales better under contention than FastMM and because it is rock solid, and most importantly so that I can have allocate multiple distinct heaps which allows me to write a program that works well with NUMA.

Comment: If you want to find memory leaks, why not use FastMM or madExcept? Or there are other tools but these are the ones I know best.

Comment: The application is really huge... mammoth huge and FastMM is too heavy (cannot run in real-time), so I would need exactly what you answered below. A custom memory manager and WinDbg or umdh. I hope it will get me somewhere (damn Delphi).

Comment: The madExcept option might be useful to you. I suspect that it is less invasive in terms of performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`!heap` works with memory allocated by calls to `HeapAlloc`, `HeapReAlloc` etc. Delphi's default memory manager uses `VirtualAlloc` and then implements its own sub-allocator. So, Delphi's memory manager is performing analagous tasks to `HeapAlloc`. What this means though is that memory allocated by Delphi's default memory manager is not visible to `!heap`.

If you really want to use WinDbg and `!heap` then you could replace the Delphi memory manager with one built on `HeapAlloc`. Perhaps that would fit your debugging requirements. I don't quite know what is driving you to WinDbg and `!heap`.

Or if you want a native Delphi way to find leaks you can use tools like FastMM4 (the full version rather than that built in to Delphi) or madExcept 4.

As a demonstration of a simple memory manager replacement built on `HeapAlloc` I offer this unit:

```
unit HeapAllocMM;

interface

implementation

uses
  Windows;

function GetMem(Size: NativeInt): Pointer;
begin
  Result := HeapAlloc(0, 0, size);
end;

function FreeMem(P: Pointer): Integer;
begin
  HeapFree(0, 0, P);
  Result := 0;
end;

function ReallocMem(P: Pointer; Size: NativeInt): Pointer;
begin
  Result := HeapReAlloc(0, 0, P, Size);
end;

function AllocMem(Size: NativeInt): Pointer;
begin
  Result := GetMem(Size);
  if Assigned(Result) then begin
    FillChar(Result^, Size, 0);
  end;
end;

function RegisterUnregisterExpectedMemoryLeak(P: Pointer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;

const
  MemoryManager: TMemoryManagerEx = (
    GetMem: GetMem;
    FreeMem: FreeMem;
    ReallocMem: ReallocMem;
    AllocMem: AllocMem;
    RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak: RegisterUnregisterExpectedMemoryLeak;
    UnregisterExpectedMemoryLeak: RegisterUnregisterExpectedMemoryLeak
  );

initialization
  SetMemoryManager(MemoryManager);

end.
```

List that as the first unit in your .dpr file's uses clause. Once you have done this then WinDbg `!heap` should start seeing your Delphi heap allocations.

Comment: The fact that whatever is Delphi related is not reliable drives me to Windbg, umdh and similar tools. But that approach is obviously a dead end. Replacing Delphi memory manager... could be a good idea, but I'm afraid it would take months to do it. Buying some third party tools has never worked as they were supposed to.

Comment: `HeapAlloc` Delphi MM for debugging purposes can be done in 5 minutes. Both FastMM and madExcept and very good leak detection tools. FastMM won't cost you a penny. madExcept is cheap and fantastic quality.